# Factorial of a number using user defined function giving garbage value in c

Tags: c, function, dynamic-programming, factorial

I was trying to construct a program to calculate factorial using user defined function but it is giving a garbage value this program was an assignment for c-cat preparation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int accept_num();             // Function call
int fact();                   // Function call
void display_num();           // Function call
int main()
{
    int num;

    num = fact();        //calling factorial

    display_num(num);    //calling printf

}
    //take input
    int accept_num()
{
     int n;
     printf("Enter number: ");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     return n;
 }
    //calculate factorial
 int fact()
{
    int i,num1;
    unsigned long long factr=1;

    num1 = accept_num();

    for(i=1; i<=num1; i++)
    {
        factr *= i;
    }
    return factr;
}

void display_num(int num2)
{
    printf("Answer = %llu",num2);
}
```

Comment: You return `int` from `fact` instead of `unsigned long long`

Comment: `display_num` should also be modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mismatching types often leads to garbage value. After calculating factorial, you stored it to `int` type and in `display_num()` function you are printing `unsigned long long int` which has more number of bits reserved than `int`. Also if you use `int i` it will result into false value of factorial after loop iterates after limit of `int`.

Below is the refined code, replace every `int` with `unsigned long long int`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
unsigned long long int accept_num();             // Function call
unsigned long long int fact();                   // Function call
void display_num();           // Function call
int main()
{
    //changed the datatype of num
    unsigned long long int num;

    num = fact();        //calling factorial

    display_num(num);    //calling printf

}
    //take input
   unsigned long long int accept_num()
{
    //changed datatype of n
     unsigned long long int n;
     printf("Enter number: ");
     scanf("%llu",&n);
     return n;
 }
    //calculate factorial
 unsigned long long int fact()
{
    unsigned long long int i;

    //changed datatype of num1
    unsigned long long int num1;
    unsigned long long int factr=1;

    num1 = accept_num();

    for(i=1; i<=num1; i++)
    {
        factr *= i;
    }
    return factr;
}

//changed datatype of argument num2
void display_num(unsigned long long int num2)
{
    printf("Answer = %llu",num2);
}
```

Also, there are more redundant variables which can be reduced. Refer to this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
long int multiplyNumbers(int n);

int main() {
    int inputNumber;
    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&inputNumber);
    printf("Factorial of %d = %ld", inputNumber, multiplyNumbers(inputNumber));
    return 0;
}

//calculate factorial using recursion
long int multiplyNumbers(int n) {
    if (n>=1)
        return n*multiplyNumbers(n-1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Refined code has `int fact()`.  Sure about that return type?

Comment: actually return type is not the only problem, I found out that using `int i` also results in wrong answer, as after reaching the limit for `int` it will eventually get mutiplied with 0.